# Keep getting FileNotFound exception after writing to file then opening

Tags: android, android-file, vcf-vcard, android-fileprovider

I have been trying this for quite a few hours now so I'm hoping someone could point out what I'm doing wrong. Basically I am pulling a vCard string from the database and passing it off to a method which should open the vCard on the user's phone. I decided on using the FileProvider class because I need to share the file with the user's Contacts application so that the vCard can be stored in their phone and because I want to delete the file after this is done.

Here is my implementation:

```
private void downloadVCard(final String vCardString, Context context) {
    try {
        File vcardPath = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "vcards");
        File vcardFile = new File(vcardPath, "vcard.vcf");
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(vcardFile);
        outputStream.write(vCardString.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
        Uri contentUri = getUriForFile(context, "com.goartech.goar.fileprovider", vcardFile);

        // Let another application open the vcard
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "text/x-vcard");
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My FileProvider setup looks like:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.goartech.goar.fileprovider"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"
    android:exported="false">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
</provider>
```

My filepaths.xml looks like:

```
<paths>
    <files-path path="vcards/" name="vcards" />
</paths>
```

I had it working at one point where the Contacts app was trying to open the vCard file (there was no chooser presented though) but then the app would crash after a few seconds. I thought maybe it was the vCard structure so I made a very simple one and tested it, still nothing. Then I thought maybe because it was trying to open the wrong file and restructured things, but now I'm getting the FileNotFound exception again.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty unclear what this is about? You are writing a file? Ans reading one? Wat happens exactly when?

Comment: I want to write the passed vCardString to a file then have another program, i.e. Contacts open it up so that the vCard is stored in the user's contacts. The vCard has to be passed as a string so that's why I'm writing the file first.

Comment: And what are you doing to let anoter app open it? You are telling nothing.

Comment: `catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }`. Place a Toast() there that diaplays `e.getMessage()` so the user af your app knows what is happening. Which statement throws the exception? Is it really after writing? Are you shure?